# How to add one column to pandas dataframe based on values in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like below:

```
a     b    c    d   
0.7   0.1  0.2  0.3
0.5   0.2  0.2  0.2
```

I am writing some nested loops like below to add a column result based on these 4 columns.

```
def class_decider(df):
    for i in df['a']:
        if i > 0.6:
            a = "class A"
        elif:
            for j in df['b']:
                if j > 0.2:
                    a = "class B"
                elif:
                    for k in df['c']:
                        if j > 0.15:
                            a = "class C"
                        elif:
                            for l in df['d']:
                                if l > 0.10:
                                    a = "class D"
                                else:
                                    a = "null"
    return a
```

Could anyone please help in optimising the code.

Expected Output:

```
a     b    c    d     result
0.7   0.1  0.2  0.3   class A
0.5   0.2  0.2  0.2   class C
```

Comment: Please also add your expected output based on your sample dataframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, You can compare the columns `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` with  `0.6, 0.2, 0.15, 0.10` to create a boolean mask, then use `idxmax` along `axis=1` on this mask to get the name of the column where the first `True` value occur in the mask.

```
c = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
m = df[c].gt([0.6, 0.2, 0.15, 0.10])
df['Result'] = m.idxmax(1).radd('Class ').mask(~m.any(1), 'Null')
```

---

```
     a    b    c    d   Result
0  0.7  0.1  0.2  0.3  Class a
1  0.5  0.2  0.2  0.2  Class c
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these are not the only columns. There are several other columns but the "result" column is based on these four. Also, let's assume instead of "class A", "class B" etc,. it is different classes like "red", "blue" etc,.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these are not the only columns. There are several other columns but the "result" column is based on these four. Also, let's assume instead of "class A", "class B" etc,. it is different classes like "red", "blue" etc,.

Comment: @ThivagarMoorthy In that case we can select only the subset of columns. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for interpretable, flexible, but not necessarily the best performing solutions, here are two approaches:

**Approach 1**: Using `.loc` and column comparisons

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.7, 0.5], 'b':[0.1, 0.2], 'c':[0.2, 0.2], 'd':[0.3, 0.2]})
df['result'] = None
df.loc[df['d'] > 0.1, 'result'] = 'class_d'
df.loc[df['c'] > 0.15, 'result'] = 'class_c'
df.loc[df['b'] > 0.2, 'result'] = 'class_b'
df.loc[df['a'] > 0.6, 'result'] = 'class_a'
```

**Approach 2** Using `df.iterrows()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.7, 0.5], 'b':[0.1, 0.2], 'c':[0.2, 0.2], 'd':[0.3, 0.2]})
df['result'] = None

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['a'] > 0.6:
        df.loc[idx, 'result'] = 'class_a'
    elif row['b'] > 0.2:
        df.loc[idx, 'result'] = 'class_b'
    elif row['c'] > 0.15:
        df.loc[idx, 'result'] = 'class_c'
    elif row['d'] > 0.1:
        df.loc[idx, 'result'] = 'class_d'
```